# Open modal on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one css modal which opens on clicking a button but now i want to open it automatically when page loads.
Demo: http://www.cssscript.com/demo/lightweight-customizable-modal-lightbox-js-library-uglipop-js/ 
Javascript for opening modal on button click:

```
modalTrigger = function(){uglipop({class:'modalWrapper',source:'div',content:'modalDemo'});}
```

Comment: If you use jquery, you can use `.ready()`. Read up on the differences to see if your css is negatively impacted by `window.onload();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: @SaidKholov i am new here and i dont know about jQuery

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/r8jxmej1/

Comment: @HarpreetKaur did you solve your problem?

Comment: Haven't been able to get this to work. Tried @Nagesh's solution for `<body onload='modalTrigger();'>` and @Bik's solution but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

use `onload()` event `<body onload='modalTrigger();'>`

Comment: I tried onload() but its not working. Is there any another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple Just use following :-

```
<script>
modalTrigger();
</script>
```